# Add a prefix for PIPE output in c++

Tags: c++, libcurl

How do you add a prefix for the output of command execution with c++

localhost is a Flask web application

```
std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::string result;
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&_pclose)> pipe(_popen(cmd, "r"), _pclose);
    if (!pipe) {
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    }
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr) {
        result += buffer.data();
        //std::cout << typeid(result).name() << std::endl;
        
        // read form pipe and add to the output string 
        std::string output = "output=";
        output += buffer.data()
        std::cout << output << std::endl; 
        // call report_ to send a post request to the server 
        report_(output);

        
    }
    char* c = const_cast<char*>(result.c_str());

  

    return result;
}
```

As far as I understand this is a c++ function that returns a string value of the output from the command prompt

```
int report_(std::string report )
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    /* get a curl handle */
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
           just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
           data. */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/api/00000000000000000000/report");
        /* Now specify the POST data */

        // report starts with "output="
        std::cout << report << std::endl;

 
        // this is where we add the post data
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, output );

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

This function reports the output of the `exec()` function but before you do that you have to add the prefix `output=` to the output of `exec()` which takes a string as an argument

The server returns
`400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'output'`

If you change        `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, output );` to        `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "output=hello world" ); then the server receives the output`

Comment: What program is being executed? What is the output it generates? Do you url-encode the string you pass to `report_`?

Comment: I fail to understand where you want the output added ...

Comment: PS there's a buffer underflow in `while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr) {result += buffer.data();`

Comment: aaalso your exec function chokes on the first null byte printed by the program, that looks like a bug/unintentional

Comment: @hanshenrik how do you fix the null byte problem?

Comment: @tochka the null byte problem can be fixed like ```size_t bytes_read_last_attempt;
 while ((bytes_read_last_attempt=fread(buffer.data(), sizeof(char), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) > 0) {
        result.append(buffer.data(), bytes_read_last_attempt);
```
- there's surely more "c++-idiomatic" ways to fix it but it should work at least. this will fix both the buffer-underflow AND the null-byte problem

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) explains how to add post data to post fields you have to pass a pointer to the data you want to send so using `const char*`

```
// this line refers to the pointer of the string needed to be send over 
// just replace output with and std::string value and you can send it as post data 
// do not use std::string as post data 
const char* c = const_cast<char*>(output.c_str());

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, c );
```